# Scripts don't work in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3d version 5.6 and when I change a script (using Mono), it works only after reloading Unity3d. 
I have tried to install again Unity3d but nothing. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed with: Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Auto Refresh

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your automatic Asset Refresh is off - this can be disabled per project, your scripts should reload if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)

I personally use Console Enhanced Free to fine tune that behaviour, i.e. disable automatic reload if in Play Mode

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to save the script in VS before returning to Unity and playing your game. I've had problems like this before. A simple <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> will usually do it, but sometimes I have to go to File > Save All and that gets it working. If all else fails, try reloading VS instead of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to wait a few (up to 15) seconds for Unity to detect the change and recompile.  You'll notice this pause if you are on the 'Scene' window and have an animated component present (eg particle engine).  When the compilation occurs, Unity will become momentarily unresponsive.  The 'Scene' will pause and a moment later will resume.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the scripts by CTRL + R

There is a setting in Preferences/General/Auto reload

Answer (score 0):

By Default Auto Refresh is checked in Updated Unity version. If it's not checked you can checked it Unity->Preference->General->Auto Refresh